# How to Use Powershell to Kill threads of a specific processID

Tags: iis, powershell, service, pid, threadstatic

well this has been bugging me for a couple of days on and off. I am at a clients site where they have a number of bespoke, written in house, services running on a Windows 2008R2 IIS server. The problem is that a couple of these services keep hanging, they are stuck in a “Stopping” state and the only way to kill them off is to open process explorer and kill the threads. Before anyone says anything about using ‘runas’, or logging on as the local admin, or the service owner, etc we’ve been through all of that.

The problem lies with the executable itselfs. The development team, in another country are going to look at this but it will take 4-5 months minimum, and we’re not certain they’ll get it right then.

I have a Powershell script to check the services on a regular basis which has the ability to ensure the services are running and if not, the force a stop and restart of the service, then it sends an email to confirm the actions. However with these specific services mentioned it can do nothing. They can’t be killed in task manager, taskkill, or process explorer (unless one kills the threads) it just says access denied. It is possible to change the permissions in process explorer and kill it but that’s a lengthier process than killing the threads.

To make things a little more difficult I can’t use the process name as on this server there are two other websites using an exe with the same name, just in a different folder.
What I’m after is a way to find and kill the threads of a processID, which I’ve already obtained via the script I have, so the rest of the script can complete the task of restarting the said service. At the moment this service dies on an inconsistent basis throughout the day and night, and the support guys have to RDP onto the server, open process explorer, find the offending process and kill the threads off then restart the services. A bit too much hassle for these already over worked guys especially if we can get powershell to do it automatically.

Hope someone can help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Low level thread handling is likely to require native Win32 API usage. Powershell might help with P/Invoke, but the process is going to be complex. For starters, find out if the following tools can be used to identify the stuck thread. Maybe you can combine this info with some Sysinternals tools like handle.exe to find out what really blocks the thread.

The .Net framework has some tools available via `System.Diagnostics.Process` namespace. A list for threads for named process is available like so,

```
$ps = [diagnostics.process]::getProcessesByName("iexplore")
$p = $ps[0]
$p.Threads[0]
```

Full [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in MSDN. There is no method for killing a thread, but this should be kind of starting point for identifying the stuck one.

Another a way is to use WMI to get [win32_thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data like so,

```
$threads = gwmi win32_thread
```

The output is quite different and some filtering is needed. Some examples [are available](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/02/28/use-powershell-to-explore-process-threads-in-windows.aspx). Another a WMI solution attempt might be based on [Win32_process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has `Terminate` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. However, most of what you mentioned such as using gwmi win32_process and thread I had already tried. Unfortunately the terminate method takes down the process not the thread, and as such didn't work. Is it possible to change the permissions on the process via powershell?